# Docker container (Windows10, Centos7) ports

Tags: docker, ports

I have docker image (from private atomic repository) witch i run as a container in Docker (Windows10) and everything is all right:

```
docker run -d --net siecDocker --ip 172.18.0.22 --name UF -v /opt/DOCKER:/DEPLOY -p 9080:9080 -p 9043:9043 -p 9060:9060 ufek:1.0
```

I have no problem with application and url address answer on port 9043,9060,9080 locally and remotely.

When i pull this image from repository on centos7 and run it the container is running with my app but ports don`t answer.

it is the same image ! and syntax for running is also the same.
I have no idea whats wrong ?

Others images are all right only this one is problematic.

Comment: Remove the `--ip 172.18.0.22` and see if that helps. Your default bridge may not have that ip subnet that may be causing the issue

Comment: It didn't help. This ip is necessary for my app. subnet is ok. I created my net with subnet: 
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 siecDocker

Comment: Anything in container logs? what is the output of `iptables -S` and `sestatus`. Update those in your question

Comment: In log i see that websphere cant run: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.

Comment: Post complete logs to the question

Comment: [9/8/17 15:23:57:841 UTC] 00000000 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[9/8/17 15:23:57:914 UTC] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
[9/8/17 15:23:57:915 UTC] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[9/8/17 15:23:58:187 UTC] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.

Comment: What about the output of other commands i had asked?

Comment: iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: -A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9060 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

Comment: Please edit the question and post the logs there, its hard to read such things in comments

Comment: sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can see the issue now. You `sestatus` shows `Current mode: enforcing`. This means it is in strict mode and will only allow connections which are allowed.

Edit the `/etc/selinux/config` file and change the mode to permissive

**/etc/selinux/config**

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Restart your centos machines and things should start to work

Comment: I changed SELINUX to permissive and rebooted. It didnt help :(

Comment: Try `disabled` then and check

Comment: after _disabled_ stil the same: `ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.`